# Upsert to many subdocuments in one database call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a document with an array of objects.

```
Document = {
  _id: 1,
  doc_amount: 0,
  subDocsArray: [
  {      
   _id: 1,
   amount: 0   
  },
  {      
   _id: 2,
   amount: 1   
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

I can increment the doc_amount simply by doing...

```
Document.updateOne({ _id }, { $inc: { doc_amount: 1} })
```

But incrementing the amounts in subDocsArray is more tricky. If I have an array of updates for Document.subDocsArray

```
var newSubDocsArray = [
  {      
   _id: 1,
   amount: 5   
  },
  {      
   _id: 2,
   amount: 5   
  },
]
```

How would I go about incrementing all amounts in Document.subDocsArray in one call? Bearing in mind that the newSubDocsArray may not always contain every item in subDocsArray so would need to upsert.

Is that even possible?

EDIT: 
To clear something up, all the amounts in newSubDocsArray could be different values. Each existing subDoc array item amount should increment by the value of the amount in newSubDocs with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I not really answered the question in previous answer, here's a new one.

Afaik, you cannot do this in one call in Mongodb, but you need a call for each new array element. Then you can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-array-elements-that-match-arrayfilters) to update all your items matching current element. Here's an example with different behaviours :

Your original document :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "doc_amount" : 0.0, 
    "subDocsArray" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1.0, 
            "amount" : 20.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0, 
            "amount" : 31.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0, 
            "amount" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Applying this script :

```
var newSubDocsArray = [
  {      
   _id: 1,
   amount: 3  
  },
  {      
   _id: 2,
   amount: 8   
  },
    {      
   _id: 4,
   amount: 7   
  },
      {      
   _id: 5,
   amount: 9   
  },
];


newSubDocsArray.forEach(function(newSubDoc){
  db.getCollection("test").update(
    {_id:1},   
    {$inc:{"subDocsArray.$[subdoc].amount":newSubDoc.amount}},   // Note the use of $[subdoc]
    { multi: true,
       arrayFilters: [ { "subdoc._id": newSubDoc._id } ]
    }
  )
})
```

Will result :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "doc_amount" : 0.0, 
    "subDocsArray" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1.0, 
            "amount" : 23.0   // +3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0, 
            "amount" : 39.0   // +8
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0, 
            "amount" : 3.0    // unchanged
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 5.0, 
            "amount" : 9.0    // created, set to 9
        }
    ]
}
```

You can note that :

- item with _id 3 is not updated (not in new newSubDocsArray).
- item with _id 4 is NOT created in the array (arrayFilters does not match anything).
- items with _id 5 has a new amount field created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$[] array update oprator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) to achieve this :

```
db.getCollection("test").update(
  {_id:1},   
  {$inc:{"subDocsArray.$[].amount":1}}
)
```

Comment: Does this way require that the amount updates all be the same value? I'm not sure how I update the correct item inside $[].

Comment: all items inside subDocsArray will have 'amount' field increased by 1, regardless of their previous vaue (5->6, 12->13, etc...). If an item inside subDocsArray doesn't have an 'amount' field, this one will be created, and set to 1.

Comment: I get that but that's not what I want. I need to be able to pass an array of different amounts. I don't want them to all increase by the same amount, but per the amounts in newSubDocsArray.

Answer (score -1):

You can updated the sub array item with $ like

give the criteria first  { _id: 1,'subDocsArray._id' : 1}

then update items like : {$inc  :{'subDocsArray.$.amount':1}}

Comment: According to the doc : 
    - the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and
    - the array field must appear as part of the query document.
So this will not do the asking job, but update only the first array element.

Comment: so you want to increment all array values ? you can do that by this { $inc: { "subDocsArray.$" : 1 } }

Comment: and where is your 'amount' field? you cannot do that with non numeric type object.

Comment: {$inc:{"subDocsArray.$[].amount":1}}

Comment: and what is my (first) answer... ? Tada !!